# Which websocket server implementation can be combined with rabbitmq?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, websocket, rabbitmq

Hi there we are planning on integrating a websocket server implementation as frontend to our RabbitMQ systems. Currently we are running some Java/Groovy/Grails based apps which use the RabbitMQ server.

We would like to have a simple websocket server implementation that handles connections etc and that passes the request to our RabbitMQ layer.

Clients (hardware devices) would connect to a websocket layer that handles the request to RabbitMQ. Some other process takes on the job of handling the request and places back data in the queue if needed so that RabbitMQ is able to pass the data via websockets back to the client.

I am a bit lost in the land of websockets so i am wondering what other people would advise to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use rabbitmq itself with the webstomp plugin and sock.js for web frontends. You can expose this directly or via something like haproxy.

http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2012/05/14/introducing-rabbitmq-web-stomp/

In version 3.x it is now included by default,  just enable the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

For Java there are a couple of choices:

- Atmosphere
- Vert.x
- Play 2.0
- Netty directly

There are so many ways to skin the cat. Atmosphere will probably get you the furthers if you already using Grails. You will have to write a custom `Broadcaster` IIRC there is not one for RabbitMQ but you can just copy one of the existing ones.

Also with RabbitMQ or any queue your going to have to decide whether your going to make queues for each for each user (browser using websocket) or your going to aggregate based on some hash and then dispatch internally (ie make a giant map of mailboxes). Akka would be a good choice for mapping to mailboxes.